# Convert use of Membership to something that will work in .NET Core for WCF service calls

Tags: wcf, authentication, cookies, .net-core

I have some legacy framework code that calls a service that I need to replicate in a .NET Core 3.1 solution.  The code uses a client built by adding a web reference (ImageService).  The code authenticates the user using Membership and sets an authentication cookie that is used by the execution of client methods.

The method below is what I need to replicate in the Core solution.  I've created a client in the .NET Core solution also using the WCF web reference.  What do I need to do/use to replicate the functionality of the code below?

```
    private static void setImageService(string host, string userId, string password) {
        ImageService.ImageService _imageServiceSoapClient = new ImageService.ImageService();
        ((ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider).ServiceUri = string.Format("https://{0}/ImageService/Authentication_JSON_AppService.axd", host);
        ((ClientRoleProvider) Roles.Provider).ServiceUri = string.Format("https://{0}/ImageService/Role_JSON_AppService.axd", host);
        bool validateUser = Membership.ValidateUser(userId, password);
        if (validateUser) {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidCredentialException(string.Format("User {0} not authenticated", userId));
        }
        _imageServiceSoapClient.CookieContainer = ((ClientFormsIdentity) Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).AuthenticationCookies;
    }
```

Comment: You only need to add a service reference on the client side and then generate a proxy class to call WCF services in the core. It should be noted that core only supports BasicHttpBinding, CustomBinding, NetHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding. In addition, there are some other restrictions, for more information you can refer to this link: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain properly.  I've already created the service reference and proxy on the client side.  The current (Framework) solution adds the authenticated principle cookies to proxy's CookieContainer to be used with service calls.  That is what I need to replicate.

Comment: What binding is used on your server-side?